# Cannot open file with underscores using the SD library

Tags: arduino-mega, sd-card

So I'm trying to create a new file that has underscores in its name. However, when I try this, no file is created.

**This works**

```
String fileName = "NMEA.txt";
mySensorData = SD.open(fileName.c_str(), FILE_WRITE);
```

**This does not work**

```
String fileName = "NMEA__23_33_3__16_7_29.txt";
mySensorData = SD.open(fileName.c_str(), FILE_WRITE);
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [The SD library] uses short 8.3 names for files.

[source](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SD)

Comment: Do you have any tips on how I can organize my files then? As you can see in the above format, I have it as NMEA__hr_mn_ss__yr_mm_dd.txt.

Comment: I tried `String fileName = "/23_33_3/16_7_29/NMEA.txt"` to organize it by directory and it doesn't seem to create them.

Comment: Have you actually created those directories? It won't magically make them for you...